# how to apply table sorter for nested headers in table?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, tablesorter

in a single table the tablesorter functionality working fine.But i am confusing to apply the table sorter for the below scnario.

```
ID  Name    Phone
1   vasu    4562789
Role    status  submitted
admin   completed   yes
user    notcompleted    no
2   venkat  78979789
Role    status  submitted
admin   completed   yes
3   balu    768792
Role    status  submitted
user    completed   yes
4   jj  897422
Role    status  submitted
user    completed   no



<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#maintbl").tablesorter();
</script>
<table class="tablesorter" id="maintbl">
<thead>
  <th>id</th>
  <th>name</th>
  <th>phone</th>
  <thead> 
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td><%: id%></td>
  <td><%: name%></td>
<td><%: phone%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>
<table id="childtbl">
<thead>
  <th>appid</td>
  <th>appname</th>
</thead>
<tr>
 <td><%: appid%></td>
 <td><%: appname%></td>
</tr>
</table>  
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

like the above my table design is available.I want to apply the sorter functionality.

If i am applying the sorting functionality to "maintbl" the child tables records are not ordering .
I need to sort records based on maintbl headers.how to sort the childtable according the maintbl values.i mean need to sort the values based on maintbl only.how to do this?

Comment: $("#childtbl").tablesorter();

Comment: i need to sort the records based on maintbl id,name,phone headers.if i am trying to sort by id then child records also should sort becuse child value is nothing but maintbl td only. ?

Comment: I'm not sure which browser you plan on supporting, but some older browsers may need proper markup - include a `tbody` and `td` inside of `tr`'s, etc... but other than that, it works:  http://jsfiddle.net/abkNM/2399/

Comment: @Mottie.little bit confusing can you please check my table design above.if i am click on maintbl headers should sort the table header content and also child content.in your fiddle header content is not avaible.only one child is there.in my table maintbl headers and it's content ,child table headers ,child table content.when click on maintbl header should sort the records based on maitbl headers content.but child content is altering differently,please check this and let me know...

Comment: @Mottie ,can you check my table design once in above edited question.in above table i need to sort the records based on id,name and phone headers.please tell me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The shared HTML markup won't work because the child table is in a row with only one td and no colspan... Here is how, I think, the markup should look like ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/abkNM/2414/)):

HTML (showing only one entry)

```
<table class="tablesorter" id="maintbl">
    <thead>
        <th>id</th>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>phone</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <!-- one parent + child row containing a child table -->
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>vasu</td>
            <td>4562789</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="tablesorter-childRow">
            <td colspan="3">
                <table class="childtbl">
                    <thead>
                        <th>Role</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Submitted</th>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>admin</td>
                            <td>completed</td>
                            <td>yes</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>user</td>
                            <td>notcompleted</td>
                            <td>no</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Script

```
$(function(){
    $('#maintbl').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        sortList: [[1, 0]],
        widgets: ['zebra', 'columns']
    });

    $('.childtbl').tablesorter({
        theme: 'blue',
        sortList: [[0, 0]],
        widgets: ['zebra', 'columns']
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi @Mottie same sample i am trying in sample mvc page it's not working properly.same code i copied and paste in mvc view page when sorting childs ,parents are seperating eachother instead of showinf out put in fiddle.

Comment: Make sure the wrap the script within a document ready event (see edited answer) `$(function(){ /* all code goes here */ });`