# table sorter with multiple headers?

Tags: jquery, tablesorter

my table design like the below.
Id,Name,Phone are main headers.I need to apply sorting based on these headers only.
When click on Id,should sort based on id values 1,2,3,4 like that name and phone .
But in below design child content header also there.If i am applying sorting on main headers child content positions altering differently.
Please tell me how to sort the below table design with Id,Name,Phone headers.

```
ID  Name    Phone
1   vasu    4562789
Role    status  submitted
admin   completed   yes
user    notcompleted    no
2   venkat  78979789
Role    status  submitted
admin   completed   yes
3   balu    768792
Role    status  submitted
user    completed   yes
4   jj  897422
Role    status  submitted
user    completed   no
```

Please check the above table design and give me idea to sort the table using tablesorter with Id,Name,Phone headers.

Comment: You may like to use the Flexi grid, they have a demo grid on site here, http://flexigrid.info/

Comment: Table design is confusing, with ID 1 there are two roles?

Comment: with in that ID header (Role ,status submitted )are headers for that ID.roles may contain many rows(1,2,3 rows etc).

Comment: i need to sort the records based on id,name and phone not with role,status ,submitted.when click on id sohuld sort(1,2,3,4)order.

Comment: please tell me i didn't get idea to acheive this

Comment: possible duplicate of [how to apply table sorter for nested headers in table?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845076/how-to-apply-table-sorter-for-nested-headers-in-table)

Comment: Please see the answer I posted in your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22845076/how-to-apply-table-sorter-for-nested-headers-in-table)... there is no need to duplicate questions here.